# Using IF function with multiple conditions

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an Excel report where I have to convert money (Column O in the picture) into EUR currency:
[image]

So far I have been using the IF function, but here the pattern is a bit different. Instead of

```
=IF(Condition;"true";"false")
```

I need rather

```
=IF(P2='EUR';O2);IF(P2='USD';O2*0,78);IF(P2='GBP';O2*1,25);
```

Just it does not work as it's not a correct Excel expression.
Any help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this...

```
=IF(P2='EUR';O2;IF(P2='USD';O2*0,78;IF(P2='GBP';O2*1,25;NA())))
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to nest the `IF` function calls, i.e.

```
IF(Condition1;Result1;IF(Condition2;Result2;If(Condition3;Result3;SomeDefault)))
```

Example here:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

First arrange a currency values table versus euro for example I did that in sheet 2 on below image

[image]

then you can use the formula:
`=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(P2,Sheet2!$A$1:$B$4,2,0)*O2),"Incorrect urrency",VLOOKUP(P2,Sheet2!$A$1:$B$4,2,0)*O2)`

Comment: This is actually a pretty clever solution. Very relational-database-like. Love it.

Comment: Already chosen the right answer, thanks anyway for sharing the tip!

Answer (score 1):

Right. I don't have excel, but I did it on Google Spreadsheets, and it works. 
So what you have to do is to nest the conditions, such as:

```
=IF(B1="EUR";A1;IF(B1="GBP";A1*1,25;A2*0,78))
```

So you will get something like:

[image: Sample]

Hope this helps!